# Measuring Variable Effect in Random Forest Regressor

Tags: random-forest, regression-coefficients

Is there a way to measure the effect individual predictors have on an outcome for a Random Forest Regressor?

If there's not something similar to a regression coefficient, is there a way to utilize importance measures (MSE,etc.) as a sort of proxy measure?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most famous capabilities of random forest is the ease to estimate the importance of a predictor. In fact, this is called "variable importance" in Leo Breiman's original paper.

In the R package randomForest, after a model is fitted, you can get the variable importance by

mod$importance

which gives you a matrix of two columns. There are as many rows as the number of predictors. For any predictor row, the first column gives you an estimate of how much worse in terms of accuracy your model would have been had you omitted this predictor; the second column is the increase in MSE had this predictor not included in the model.

Comment: My understanding of importance measures is that they simply reveal how much a particular feature contributes to a particular prediction, not the degree to which they contribute. What I'm looking for is a measure, similar to a regression coefficient, that reveals the potential amount that a feature contributes to a unit change in the outcome. Is there a way to derive that from importance measures?

Comment: Since it is a decision tree based method, you won't get things like coefficients as in regression. The best way to judge is the number of splitting rules used for each variable and then you can standardize that number to come up with relative importance measure. It can be what you are looking for in terms of "degree"